# SOQL query DATE comparison

Tags: soql

How do I compare a date field?

I have 2 objects ObjectA and ObjectB and I would like to run a query for ObjectB that is DateFieldB = DateFieldA.

Here is my Line:

```
for(ObjectA__c A : Trigger.New)
{
        if(A.DateFieldA__c != NULL)
        {
            Map<Id, ObjectB__c> B = new MapMap<Id, ObjectB__c> 
            (
                [
                SELECT Id, DateFieldDateB__c
                FROM ObjectB__c
                WHERE DateFieldB__c = A.DateFieldA__c
                ]
            );
        }
 }
```

I am having this error:

```
Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found A.DateFieldA__c at line 13 column 40.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the date from object A into a temporary variable:

`Date tempDate = A.DateFieldA__c;`

and then reference this variable in the SOQL query (note the semicolon)

`[SELECT Id FROM ObjectB__c WHERE DateFieldB__c = :tempDate];`

Comment: hmmm ... sounds logical. let me give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Bachovski, since DateFieldA__c is actually a Datea/Time field.

Can I just do Date TempDate = DATEVALUE(A.DateFieldA__C)?
Thanks Again.

Comment: No you need to do: `tempDate = A.DateFieldA__c.date();` - Check the datetime methods - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm